# Splitting files from 1 file in for loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, with-statement

So my current code looks at a .txt file and splits it into 2 different files based on similarities found within the file. I want to look at one of these files and split it up into 2 different files based on the same condition. I would like to repeat this process until all similarities have been found. I was able to get the main file to split into 2 different files successfully, but I haven't been able to get the split file to split into more files. How could I solve this problem?

If this helps, here's an analogy of what I want to accomplish:

A big bag of apples (bag 1) -> Put all granny smith apples into bag 2, other apples into another bag (bag 3) -> put all Fuji apples from bag 3 into bag 4, put remaining apples into bag 5 -> put all red delicious apples from bag 5 into bag 6, put remaining apples into bag 7... repeat until all apples have been separated into different bags

```
import os, sys
input_file = sys.argv[1]

output_directory = os.path.split(input_file)[0]
output_file_name = os.path.split(input_file)[1]
output_short_name, output_extension = os.path.splitext(output_file_name)
similar_output_path = os.path.join(output_directory, output_short_name + "_similar_split" + output_extension)
unsimilar_output_path = os.path.join(output_directory, output_short_name + "_r0" + output_extension)
similar_output_file = open(similar_output_path, 'w') # bag #2 from the example; this file has the correct output 
unsimilar_output_file = open(unsimilar_output_path, 'w') # bag #3 from the analogy; this file has the correct output

list = ['red delicious apple1','red delicious apple2','red delicious apple3','fuji apple1','fuji apple2', 'fuji apple3', 'fuji apple4', 'granny smith1','granny smith2', 'granny smith3', 'golden delicious 1', 'golden delicious 2', 'gala1', 'gala2', 'gala3']

for index, item in enumerate(list):
  split_output_path = os.path.join(output_directory, output_short_name + "_unsimilar_split_r" + str(index) + output_extension)
  with open(os.path.join(output_directory, output_short_name + "_unsimilar_split_r" + str(index) + output_extension)) as split_input:
    with open(os.path.join(output_directory, output_short_name + "_r" + str(index + 1) + output_extension)) as split_unsimilar_output_file:
      parse_function(item, split_input,split_unsimilar_output_file)
```

Comment: Give it a try and we can guide you.

Comment: I'm getting an error of "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<file-path.\\<file-name>-r1.txt'

Comment: Please complete the MCVE: provide an input file and the full output (i.e. error message with traceback).